# CommTimeout and parameters c++

Tags: c++, port, communication

I'm currently dealing with the [`COMMTIMEOUTS` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363190.aspx).  I'm doing my best to read in a maximum of 75 characters via RS232C and I want a timeout after 20 seconds.

Currently what I have is this:

```
this->m_cTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
this->m_cTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 20000;
this->m_cTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
```

However, it just seems to read until 103s when it auto kicks off.  Any ideas?

I do set the `COMMTIMEOUT` in another function, so I'm fairly confident that this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation more carefully:

> **ReadIntervalTimeout**
> The maximum time allowed to elapse before the arrival of the next byte on the communications line, in milliseconds. If the interval between the arrival of any two bytes exceeds this amount, the ReadFile operation is completed and any buffered data is returned. **A value of zero indicates that interval time-outs are not used.**
>
> A value of MAXDWORD, combined with zero values for both the ReadTotalTimeoutConstant and ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier members, specifies that the read operation is to return immediately with the bytes that have already been received, even if no bytes have been received.
>
> **ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier**
> The multiplier used to calculate the total time-out period for read operations, in milliseconds. **For each read operation, this value is multiplied by the requested number of bytes to be read.**
>
> **ReadTotalTimeoutConstant**
> A constant used to calculate the total time-out period for read operations, in milliseconds. **For each read operation, this value is added to the product of the ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier member and the requested number of bytes.**

If you are reading 75 bytes and want a 20s max timeout, you can set the `ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier` to `20000 / 75 = 266`, which is **75 * 266 = 19950ms**, and set the `ReadTotalTimeoutConstant` to `50` for the remaining **50ms**.